# How to find out how many blog posts I have made?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

How to find out how many blog posts I have made? i tried to do this in my view, but I got "request is not defined".

```html
<div class="form-group">
     <input class="form-control bg-white form-control-plaintext text-dark" 
            type="number" placeholder="Number of Posts: {{ num_blogpost }}"
            readonly></input>
</div>
```

my view

```py
class BlogView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    template_name = 'HomeFeed/formview.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context= super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        user = request.user
        blog_post = get_object_or_404(BlogPost, slug=slug)
        num_blogpost = BlogPost.objects.filter(author=user).count()
        return context
```

My **models.py**

```py
class BlogPost(models.Model):
 chief_title = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
 body        = models.TextField(max_length=5000, null=False, blank=False)
 author      = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view you can use `self.request` (because you are using class-based-views) instead of just `request`.

```py
class BlogView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ...
        user = self.request.user
        blog_post = get_object_or_404(BlogPost, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        ...
```

Surprisingly, this is only documented in one place (that I could find), https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#dynamic-filtering:

> [...] when class-based views are called, various useful things are stored on `self`; as well as the request (`self.request`) this includes the positional (`self.args`) and name-based (`self.kwargs`) arguments captured according to the URLconf.

Comment: hey man now it says slug is not defined. Do I also do `self.slug`? @Ralf

Comment: wait no i cant do self.slug because my view is not related to my blog post.

Comment: @JackalLee try `self.kwargs['slug']`, assuming that `slug` is part of your URL parameters

Answer (score -1):

you can do it in the html like

```
 {{q_search_customers.count}}
```